# massaging packages that install files outside of nix-store

Tags: nix

I'm using nix package-manager on macOS (Sierra).

My intention is to write a nix expression that will install the existing [fish](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/af7e47921c481c3b1677e6b25755760a8ff9c411/pkgs/shells/fish/default.nix) nix package along with the [Bass](https://github.com/edc/bass) fish plugin.

There are no existing expressions in nixpkgs for Bass, but the git repo contains a [Makefile](https://github.com/edc/bass/blob/master/Makefile). This Makefile attempts to copy files to the `$HOME` dir. This is a problem as installing files outside of the nix-store is clearly not desirable and `$HOME` is not set when I build my package.

I can recognise why it's not desirable for nix packages to install files outside of the nix-store - in functional programming terms it's akin to a side-effect. But I'm also not clear on how to solve my problem:

By default Fish requires plugins such as Bass to be installed under `$HOME/.config/fish/`. Fish does provide a means to customise the config path by specifying the environment variable `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`. So I was thinking of doing something like this:

1. Create an expression for Bass patching the Makefile to install the files under $out.
2. Create an expression that installs fish and uses Bass as a build input. Use `wrapProgram` to set `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` pointing to the Bass install path in the nix-store.

Does this sound like the right approach? Are there alternative/better ways of solving this?

Thanks

Comment: Your approach sounds good. I say, try it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution that I have gone with:

**Expression for bass**:
 `nix_local/pkgs/fish_plugins/bass/default.nix`

```
{stdenv, fetchFromGitHub}:

let
  version = "0.0.1";

in
stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name = "bass-${version}";

  src = fetchFromGitHub {
    owner = "edc";
    repo = "bass";
    rev = "1fbf1b66f52026644818016015b8fa9e0f639364";
    sha256 = "12bp8zipjbikasx20yz29ci3hikw0ksqlbxbvi2xgi4g6rmj7pxp";
  };

  patchPhase = ''
    substituteInPlace Makefile --replace \
    "~/.config/fish" \
    $out/.config/fish
  '';
}
```

**Expression for fish_with_config:**
`nix_local/pkgs/fish_with_config/default.nix`

```
{stdenv, fish, bass, makeWrapper}:

let
  version = "0.0.1";

in
stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name = "fish-with-config-${version}";

  src = ./.;

  buildInputs = [fish bass makeWrapper];

  installPhase = ''
    mkdir -p $out/.config/fish/functions

    cp -r $src/.config/* $out/.config

    cp -r ${bass}/.config/fish/functions/* \
    $out/.config/fish/functions/

    mkdir -p $out/bin
    ln -s ${fish}/bin/fish $out/bin/fish

    wrapProgram $out/bin/fish --set XDG_CONFIG_HOME "$out/.config"
  '';
}
```

The Fish program is wrapped in order for it's config to be stored in the nix-store. This enables us to symlink the functions from Bass and also copy any additional config files from the local `$src` dir. Additional plugins could be symlinked in the same way.

The local `src` dir for the derivation contains the following files:

```
pkgs/fish_with_config
├── .config
│   └── fish
│       ├── fishd.8c8590486f8c
│       └── functions
└── default.nix
```

The `.config/fish/fishd.8c8590486f8c` file is a "universal variable file" which Fish requires in order to operate. In a standard Fish installation this file is stored under `~/config/fish/` and is created the first time you enter interactive mode. The contents of this file would typically change over time as users interact with Fish settings.

The `fish_with_config` derivation stores the Fish config in the nix-store, which means it can't be modified at a latter date (not writable). This means all the config settings need to be done upfront as any attempts by the user to modify the settings will result in permission errors - this is obviously a little inconvenient, but not a show stopper for me.

It's probably worth noting that the universal variable file may change with different releases of Fish and as such if I was to build `fish_with_config` with a newer version of Fish I would first determine it's default content by running fish in a nix-shell and inspecting the auto generated file under `~/config/fish/`.

In summary the above works nicely, I have access to `bass` and any additional user defined functions I choose to "bake in" (`pkgs/fish_with_config/.config/fish/functions`).

If you see anything that could be improved or handled more idiomatically let me know.